# How to use echo in url

Tags: php, html, json

i am trying to use echo inside url. i have store data from the form in database and now i am also fetching it on my page and its working well. Now i am trying to print that data i.e. number and date in url.

Is it possible and if possible please help me out

here is my data that i am fetching and it prints the output

```
echo $number;
echo $yyyymmdd;
```

and here is my url in which i want to insert ' echo $number; ' and ' echo $yyyymmdd; ' on the place of  and .

```
 $json= file_get_contents("http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/<number>/date/<yyyymmdd>/");
```

I have also tried something like this but it gives error of syntex error.

```
$json= file_get_contents("http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/"echo $number;"/date/"echo $yyyymmdd;"/");
```

Comment: You can do it like this.
`$json= file_get_contents("http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/".$date."/".$number);`

Comment: thanks bro, its worked for me........

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add changing parameters to a URL (or string) is by using [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). You define your URL and a type specifier like `%d` as a placeholder for numbers, and `%s` for strings. See the php doc for the full list of type specifiers.

```
$urlFormat = "http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/%d/date/%s/"
                                                                       ^       ^
```

Then call sprintf with the changing parameters in order of appearance.

```
$url = sprintf($urlFormat, $number, $yyyymmdd);
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

This becomes more convenient especially if you are calling file get contents in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables and append those two inside double-quote or single quote, depending upon the quotes which you have opened and close it.

```
<?php
$number=123;
$yyyymmdd='2018-10-9';

$json= file_get_contents("http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/".$number."/<number>/date/<".$yyyymmdd.">/");
?>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score -1):

```
$json= file_get_contents("http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/".$number."/date/".$yyyymmdd."/");
```

When you compose text, you do not need "echo" but just can write variable.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use variables in double quotes like this

file_get_contents("http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/**$number**/date/**$yyyymmdd**/");

Sample code below

```
$number = 344;
$yyyymmdd = "20180301";

$url1 = "http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/$number/date/$yyyymmdd/";
echo "url1 ".$url1."\n";

$url2 = "http://api.com/api/a2/live/apikey/fc5a69f870fdb03/number/".$number."/date/".$yyyymmdd."/";
echo "url2 ".$url2. "\n";
```